# Website redirecting to Adobe Flash Player is needed page

Tags: flash, redirect, web, opencart

I have an opencart website. The site was working perfectly, but all of a sudden my website keeps frequently redirecting to Adobe Flash Player is needed page. I am using pav styleshop theme, and I couldn't find anything using flash. this is the redirecting page [link](http://update.adobe.macromedia.katyaflash.com/?0.031314073307233695=0.6388724892588054). My site is running in localhost. Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Looks like some virus. It claims my Flash version is v14.5.502.146 and I must update (really my version is 22.0.0.209).  Flash Player is made by Adobe and only their website has the **[correct version](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)**. Never click to install if the web address is not **adobe.com**. Anyways... check your website source code for a mention of "http://update.adobe.macromedia.katyaflash.com " and either delete that re-direct section or do a new output of website...

Comment: Must be some plugin you used. Do you tried to find any **swf** extension in your folders or in your code?

Comment: I have checked for "update.adobe.macromedia.katyaflash.com" and swf file in my code, but didn't return anything helpful. So i freshly installed the theme in other place, then I changed the database of fresh one to the corrupted one's database. I am getting an error there also. So I assumed that the error is in database. but I couldn't find anything wrong in my database.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late. Though i wish to share the knowledge what I gained. As **VC.One** Suggested, it was a virus attack and it was affected in my database. So I manually delete each table to find the infected table. At last I found the affected table and row in database. There was a malicious script to redirect to some random pages. Removed that snippet and everything works fine there after.

Comment: Would have been nice to see the malicious row so we could add it as a search to scan for garbage in the DB. Even better if you knew how it got in there! :)